# Add an Angular2 Modal to my project

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

Hy, I want to add a Modal to my project. I'm using `Angular-cli`; my Angular version is `2.1.0`, Bootstrap : `4`

I tried to use `ng2-bootstrap` and `ng2-bs3-modal` but I didn't found a simple example, so I'm confused.

Can anyone give me a simple example of an angular2 modal with a "OK" and "CANCEL" buttons, having to possibility to handle events on buttons.

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal has several examples. But it uses ng-bootstrap, not ng2-bootstrap.

Comment: thank u, it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting Angular 2 and Bootstrap 4 I would suggest using the ng-bootstrap project witch has a very flexible Modal implementation: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal

Setup and usage is very simple and you could open a modal from your component calling the `open` method on the `NgbModal` service:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-basic',
  templateUrl: 'src/modal-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdModalBasic {
  closeResult: string;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return  `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
}
```

As mentioned in your question comments there are several examples and you can even fork plunkers with self-contained code, ex.: http://plnkr.co/edit/lM0GzDAqv0EYQ4qWit05?p=preview

Comment: it works fine. thank u  (but there's some issues in events when we add a customised modals)

Answer (score -2):

try to use ng-window, it's allow developer to open and full control multiple windows in single page applications in simple way, No Jquery, No Bootstrap.

https://github.com/BahgatMashaly/ng-window
[image]

Avilable Configration

- Maxmize window
- Minimize window
- Custom size,
- Custom posation
- the window is dragable
- Block parent window or not
- Center the window or not
- Pass values to chield window
- Pass values from chield window to parent window
- Listening to closing chield window in parent window
- Listen to resize event with your custom listener
- Open with maximum size or not
- Enable and disable window resizing
- Enable and disable maximization
- Enable and disable minimization